# Python UnicodeDecodeError thrown when bringing Chinese Chars from Oracle to json.dump

Tags: python, json, oracle, encoding, pyodbc

I'm querying financial data from an Oracle DB with pyodbc - every field comes through great and can dump out to json data which I then display on a webpage.

I can't seem to figure out what is going with the 17th field - '\xab\xed\xa5\xcd\xab\xfc\xbc\xc6' - when I print it to the screen, Python shows up the proper Chinese - but when I output it either the Chinese characters get lost in the json dump OR the characters throw the following error.

I've assumed this is a bytestring I should decode and then re-encode, but re-encoding as ascii or UTF8 always throws an error here.

Does anyone have a suggestion to help me out? I've spent days playing with reading up on encoding and still can't seem to understand why the utf-8 character is thrown.

The exact error is: : 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte and it occurs only on some of the Chinese characters that I'm spitting out to JSON - but none of the characters look right when the json is loaded.

```
for row in cur.fetchall(): 
    print row 
    print row[17]
    jsonData = json.dumps(row[17].decode('utf-8'), encoding='latin1')
```

This results in the following output:

```
> ('.HSI', 'HANG SENG INDEX', Decimal('1'), '+21316.47', '-21.34',
> '+1457369960', '0', '0', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 18, 0, 0, 55),
> datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 8, 1, 22), '+21423.06', '+21234.12',
> '344', Decimal('0'), '+21374.65', '+21337.81', '0',
> '\xf9\xda\xa5\xcd\xab\xfc\xbc\xc6', None, '+19163.8', '118', '-0.10',
> '+9.43', '+28588.52', '+18278.80', '-21.34', '0', '0', '0', '0',
> '-0.10', '\xab\xed\xa5\xcd\xab\xfc\xbc\xc6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
> '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0#.HSI', Decimal('1'), '.HSI',
> datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 17, 23, 58, 18))
> 恒生指數
>  return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: 
> invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - this was definitely just an encoding issue - not knowing what character encoding I was getting, like every post says, was the bane of my existence for the past few days. I managed to get time on the host machine and after much reading, I checked what the system encoding was as follows:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.encoding
```

This returned:

```
> 'cp950'
```

I then used ord() to spit out the encoded data to prepare for the JSON dump:

```
outputStr = ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in s).decode('cp950')
```